# Add single color background to texture using shader

Tags: unity, shaders, fragment-shader

I want to add a single color background to my texture. 
In my case, in Unity UI, I can simply create two Image components, one on top of another, and use the one on the bottom as a single color background.
However, I would like to do it in a single draw call, using a shader. This is the shader that I use:

```
   Shader "UI/Background Tinted"
   {
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData]_MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BgClip ("Offset Mask", Range(0,0.1)) = 0.025

        _StencilComp ("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
        _Stencil ("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
        _StencilOp ("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
        _StencilWriteMask ("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
        _StencilReadMask ("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255

        _ColorMask ("Color Mask", Float) = 15

        [Toggle(UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP)] _UseUIAlphaClip ("Use Alpha Clip", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue"="Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector"="True"
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }

        Stencil
        {
            Ref [_Stencil]
            Comp [_StencilComp]
            Pass [_StencilOp]
            ReadMask [_StencilReadMask]
            WriteMask [_StencilWriteMask]
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest [unity_GUIZTestMode]
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask [_ColorMask]

        Pass
        {
            Name "Default"
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "UnityUI.cginc"

            #pragma multi_compile __ UNITY_UI_CLIP_RECT
            #pragma multi_compile __ UNITY_UI_ALPHACLIP

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 worldPosition : TEXCOORD1;
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            fixed4 _TextureSampleAdd;
            float4 _ClipRect;
            float _BgClip;

            v2f vert(appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(OUT);
                OUT.worldPosition = v.vertex;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(OUT.worldPosition);

                OUT.texcoord = v.texcoord;

                OUT.color = v.color;
                return OUT;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                half4 main = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord);

                float mask = 1.0 - main.a;

                half4 bg = IN.color;
                bg.a = mask;

                half4 color = main + (bg * mask);

                return color;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

With two Images component everything is fine. However, with single shader approach I encounter sharp edges near image alpha boundaries.

Using 2 images, looking fine:
[image: two images]

Using single shader, jagged edges:
[image: with shader]

How do i fix that, using a single shader approach?

Comment: You forgot to dim down the main texture where it's fading out,  Both main and bg should be modulated by alpha — main fading out, and bg fading in as the alpha drops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using the following code in pixel shader:

```
            float mask = 1.0 - main.a;

            half4 bg = IN.color;
            bg.a = mask;

            half4 color = half4((main.rgb * main.a + bg.rgb * bg.a), main.a + bg.a);

            return color;
```

Comment: You can also do this using `lerp(bg, main, main.a)`